# Unable to write policy document in aws cdk using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS CDK. I am trying to create policy. Below is my code.

```
MWSECSServiceRole = iam.Role(self, 'MWSECSServiceRole',
          assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs.amazonaws.com'))

        MWSECSServiceRole.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=["arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:loadbalancer/app/mws-*","arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:listener-rule/app/mws-*","arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:listener/app/mws-*","arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:targetgroup/mws-*"],
        actions=["elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer","elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets","elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer","elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"]
        ))

        MWSECSServiceRole.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=["*"],
        actions=["ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress","ec2:Describe*","elasticloadbalancing:Describe*"]
        ))
```

Which will generate below cloud formation template.

```
MWSECSServiceRoleDefaultPolicyD5E258B0:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer
              - elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets
              - elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer
              - elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:loadbalancer/app/mws-*
              - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:listener-rule/app/mws-*
              - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:listener/app/mws-*
              - arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:{AccountId}:targetgroup/mws-*
          - Action:
              - ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
              - ec2:Describe*
              - elasticloadbalancing:Describe*
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: "*"
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      PolicyName: MWSECSServiceRoleDefaultPolicyD5E258B0
      Roles:
        - Ref: MWSECSServiceRole966AC1F9
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: LocationCdkStack-cdkstack/MWSECSServiceRole/DefaultPolicy/Resource
```

When I try to deploy It throws below error.

```
The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: e54462f7-f0bc-4a8c-9ec4-9530125113ec)
```

Can someone help me to identify this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is `{AccountId}` a real account id redacted here? What are you trying to do with `{AccountId}`?

Comment: AccountId = core.Environment.account;

Comment: Accoun id is aws account id

Comment: But in your code you are using the string `{AccountId}`?

Comment: may I know is that correct? or how to use ${AWS::AccountId}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you build your ARN using [`Stack.format_arn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/Stack.html#aws_cdk.core.Stack.format_arn):

```python
my_resource = core.Stack.of(self).format_arn(
  service="elasticloadbalancing",
  resource="loadbalancer",
  resource_name="app/mws-*"
)
```

See also [ARN Manipulation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core.README.html#arn-manipulation).

Alternatively you can concatenate string and use [`core.Stack.of(self).account`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/Stack.html#aws_cdk.core.Stack.account):

```python
my_resource = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:" + core.Stack.of(self).account + ":loadbalancer/app/mws-*"
```

Comment: so core.Stack.of(self).account is ised to get account id?

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.core/Stack.html#aws_cdk.core.Stack.account